# Bootstrap/KO: Date / Time Picker with specific Date/Time

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, datepicker

I am trying to get the following functionality:

I have a SPA that once loaded, access a REST API and receives a list of date+time values.

My goal is to be able to allow the user to select the date and time easily:

1. In case there is only one date+time value for specific date - select it by default.
2. In case there is more than one value for specific date - allow the user to select one of them via an additional popup that will show the dates.

I started off by trying to use [Bootstrap datetimepicker V3](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/). I defined a `ko.bindingHandlers` (there are plenty of examples online) but the problem is that when the binding happens and the datetime picker is initiated the observable array of valid dates is still empty (it's loaded later). I did not find a way to update the widget (I tried to register to the array change and the re-initialize the datetimepicker:

```
$el.datetimepicker('destroy'); // or 'remove'
$el.datetimepicker(options);   // after I updated options with the new enabledDates
```

Next I thought to try my luck with [bootstrap-datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/). Here, using the binding and the 'beforeShowDay' option I manged to get just the right days enabled. In the `init` function I have:

```
if (allBindingsAccessor().enabledDates) {
    var enabledDates = allBindingsAccessor().enabledDates;
    options["beforeShowDay"] = function (date) {
        for (var i = 0; i < enabledDates().length; i++) {
            var innerDate = enabledDates()[i];
            var datePart = innerDate.dateOnly();
            if (datePart.getTime() == date.getTime()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
     }
}
```

Still, when the date is selected - I try to do about the same logic to "re-translate" the whole date to exact date+time but is not functioning well (see code below).

Optimally, I would like to show some popup over the date in case there is more than one available time. Otherwise, even a two-step selection (select date and then choose time from a combo) would also work.

I created a js-fiddle that kind of shows what I have managed to do [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yaw18L1u/3/)

Is there some ready made component I can use? Does anyone has an idea how to implement?

The following code does not work properly - if I use the setDate() function I don't get anything in the bounded observable.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {

        //initialize datetimepicker with some optional options
        var options = allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions || {},
            $el = $(element);

        // in case enabledDates attribute exists, add a function to check if date exists
        // this is used later to set the exact date+time
        var getDateTime = function() {
            if (allBindingsAccessor().enabledDates) {
                // TODO: make more efficient
                var enabledDates = allBindingsAccessor().enabledDates;

                    for (var i = 0; i < enabledDates().length; i++) {
                        var td= enabledDates()[i];
                        var datePart = new Date(td.getFullYear(), td.getMonth(), td.getDate());
                        if (datePart.getTime() == date.getTime()) {
                            return innerDate;
                        }
                    }
                    return null;
            }
        };

        if (allBindingsAccessor().enabledDates) {
            var enabledDates = allBindingsAccessor().enabledDates;
            options["beforeShowDay"] = function (date) {
                for (var i = 0; i < enabledDates().length; i++) {
                    var td = enabledDates()[i];
                    var datePart = new Date(td.getFullYear(), td.getMonth(), td.getDate());
                    if (datePart.getTime() == date.getTime()) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        }

        $el.datepicker(options);

        // register to change event and update the value accessor (property) on change
        function setDate(date) {
            if (!date) {
                return date;
            }

            if (allBindingsAccessor().enabledDates) {
                var enabledDates = allBindingsAccessor().enabledDates;
                for (var i = 0; i < enabledDates().length; i++) {
                    var td = enabledDates()[i];
                    var datePart = new Date(td.getFullYear(), td.getMonth(), td.getDate());
                    if (datePart.getTime() == date.getTime()) {
                        return innerDate;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                return date;
            }
        };

        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "changeDate", function(event) {
            var value = valueAccessor();
            if (ko.isObservable(value)) {
                var actualDate = setDate(event.date);
                //console.log(actualDate);
                value(actualDate);
            }
        });

        //handle disposal (if KO removes by the template binding)
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
            $el.datetimepicker("destroy");
        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
            $el = $(element);

        var current = $el.data("datepicker").getDate();

        //var datePart = new Date(value.getFullYear(), value.getMonth(), value.getDate());
        if (value - current !== 0) {
            $el.data("datepicker").setDate(value);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Do you have a fiddle or plnkr for this ?

Comment: Added a fiddle. Meanwhile, did a workaround (see answer below)

Answer (score 0):

I did some "workaround" in which I separated the date and time picking to two distinct elements.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/yaw18L1u/20/) is a working example. In general the flow is defined:

- The user select date from available dates (handled by `beforeShowDay` function in the datepicker + an observable array passed in binding (`enabledDates` option).
- The selection of date updates the bound observable (`selectedDate`). In the model, I subscribed to the change event of the observable.
- When the `selectedDate` observable changes, I find all the date+time values that corresponds to the selected date and populate an observable array which a select picker is bound to (`avaiabledTimes`)
- The user can then select the time which is bound to an observable (`selectedTime`).  In the model I subscribe to the change event of it.
- When the `selectedTime` observable changes, I "merge" the selected date and the selected time and set the final selected date (`finalSelectedDate`).

While this kind of works, it is not 100% what I wanted:

1. The user flow is not as smooth as I wanted.
2. When I set `availabledTimes`, due to behavior of the selectpicker, the first element is selected by default which is not something I want since whenever `finalSelectedDate` changes I call some ajax routine that updates the UI - which means that in the current setup, I may get unwanted updates. (I think it maybe in the binding - I'll try to fix that as well.
3. From the code point of view - there is no encapsulation - I need figure out how to manage it all as a component (e.g. `ko.components.register('MyDateTimePicker', ...)`)